# What is the physical interpretation of the "energies" I am getting from the self-consistent field Hartree-Fock (SCF HF) method?

Tags: energy, schroedinger-equation, variational-principle, many-body

The SCF HF method is a variational method that calculates the minimal energy of a many-body ground state (actually, it converges to a number which I take as the ground state energy). But what are the second minimum, third minimum, and... energies? do they correspond to the excited states?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hamiltonian describing the electrons in a static cristal is given by $\mathcal{H} = T + U_{ions} + U_{ees}$ where $T=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\sum_i\nabla_i^2$ is the kinetic energy operator, $U_{ions} = \sum_iU_{ion}(\vec{r}_i)$ is the potential energy between the protons and the electrons and $U_{ees} = \sum_{i<j} \frac{e^2}{|\vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_j|}$ are the electron-electron interactions.

To tackle this problem, the Hartree-Fock equation assumes a collection of orthonormal one-particule spatial wave-functions $\{\phi_i(\vec{r})\}$ and applies the variational method, namely that $\langle \Psi| \mathcal{H} |\Psi \rangle \geq E_0$ where $\Psi$ is a [Slater determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater_determinant) constructed with $\{\psi_i(\vec{r},\sigma)\} = \{\phi_i(\vec{r})\chi_i(\sigma)\}$, $\{\chi_i(\sigma)\}$ the spin parts.

Since $\langle \Psi | \mathcal{H} | \Psi\rangle$ can be computed, you than minimize it with respect to $\{\phi_i\}$, add a set of Lagrange multipliers $\{\mathcal{E}_i\}$ to make sure the wave-functions are orthonormal, play a little with the solution and you get the Hartree-Fock equation 
$$
\mathcal{E}_i\phi_i(\vec{r}) = -\frac{\hbar^2\nabla^2}{2m}\phi_i(\vec{r}) + U(\vec{r})\phi_i(\vec{r}) +\phi_i(\vec{r})\int d\vec{r}' \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{e^2|\phi_j(\vec{r}')|^2}{|\vec{r}'-\vec{r}|} - \sum_{j=1}^N \delta_{\chi_i\chi_j}\phi_j(\vec{r}) \int d\vec{r}' \frac{e^2\phi^*_j(\vec{r}')\phi_i(\vec{r}')}{|\vec{r}'-\vec{r}|}.
$$
The set $\{\mathcal{E}_i\}$ is a collection of Lagrange multipliers and do not technically represent the one-particle energies of the orbitals $\{\phi_i\}$ since it is not an eigenvalue of the Hamiltonian, however it is sometimes referred to has energies but technically aren't.

Comment: Thank you, I still have a question. If I turn off the potential and solve the HF for just a 1D infinite square Well, Should I expect the plotted wave functions to be the same  as the analytical answer? or should I just expect the ground state to have the same wave function?

Comment: What do you mean, turn off the potential? You want to solve the 1D infinite square well problem using Hartree-Fock? The goal of this method is to include a part of the electronic interactions, if you don't, there isn't much interest.

Comment: If you were to try this method on this simple problem, my feeling is that you would be able to obtain a good approximation of the ground state and corresponding energy, but since it is done numerically, you would never quite get the analytical solution but could converge to it.

Comment: @gingrs.ol No, I am turning off the potential to test my code, and I want to see if it works properly for the simple 1D square well because I know what I should expect.   the funny part now I don't really know I should expect. I should expect just the ground state(n=1) to be similar to the analytical solution, Or should I get the similar eigenfunctions as analytical solution for (n=2,n=3,...). In other words in HF the energy converges  hopefully to the ground state(n=1), but how can we find the eigenfunctions and energies related to (n=2,n=3,...). Is it possible or not?

Comment: @gingrs.oh No, I am turning off the potential to test my code, and I want to see if it works properly for the simple 1D square well which I know the answer  for.   the funny part is now I don't really know what I should expect from HF. I should expect just the ground state(n=1) to be similar to the analytical solution, Or should I get the similar eigenfunctions as analytical solution for (n=2,n=3,...) too? In other words in HF the energy converges  hopefully to the ground state(n=1) , but how can we find the eigenfunctions and energies related to (n=2,n=3,...). Is it possible or not?

Comment: I think if you specify the number of electrons in the system to be N, you will fill your levels. So Hartree-Fock should calculate the eigenfunctions and values for the number of states you're requiering. If you put $N=2$, you fill $n=0$ with 2 electrons. If you put $N=3$, you have 2 electrons in $n=0$, 1 in n=1. The Hartree-Fock energy is the sum of the electrons eigenenergies, so for $N=2$ you have $E=2E_0$ and for $N=3$ you have $E=2E_0+E_1$, etc. But I'm not so sure about this, it kind of depends on the program you're using.